# Filter pcap file by layer and save to another format

Tags: wireshark, data, pcap

I captured packets in wireshark, filtered for the protocol I'm interested in (DIS), then exported this to a pcap file. I'd like to do analysis on this data in Python. The only part I'm interested in for each packet is the data layer header/data. How can I extract this from all the packets and save to something like a txt, json, or csv?

I just read about tshark and attempted a line of code I found: `tshark -r capture.pcap -T fields -e data > data.txt`, but this returns an empty file. I can see the data I'm interested in through wireshark though.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about programming are off-topic here. You can ask programming questions on [so], but they will want more information. You can simply use Python to parse the file for you prior to the analysis that you want.

Comment: It's not strictly a programming question though. I just said I want to analyze it in Python after resolving this issue. Are you saying that the only way to filter it is through Python rather than a networking tool and so that's why it's a programming question?

Comment: We cannot recommend tools. Product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic for SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se]. It would seem to me that you could simply have the application you are building do it all: parse the data then analyze it, rather than do those separately.

Comment: It's likely you have the field name wrong. Use `tshark -r capture.pcap -T json` to dump the data with it's field names, and examine that output to get the names of the fields you want to output with the `-e` option.

Answer (score 3):

Hi think you should have a look to https://scapy.net/, with not too much programming you can achieve the task of extract the packets and parsing as json, cvs or whatever.